# Moment library is returning different time date format in IE10 but working fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, momentjs, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone, moment-timezone

**moment.tz("2019-11-03T06:45:01.000Z", "America/Chicago").toDate()**

This returns ***"Nov 3, 2019, 01:45 CDT"*** in chrome and IE11 but in IE10 I'm getting output is
***"Sat Nov 2 20:45:01 CDT 2019".***

I observed something strange and where the actual formatting problem starts in moment-timezone-js function tz where

***out = moment.utc.apply(null, "2019-11-03T06:45:01.000Z");***

Edit - Error in console which I saw later:
No locale data has been provided for this object yet

Comment: `toDate` gets you a native Date object, and therefor the default “format” you get when implicitly calling the toString method of that, which is simply different in different browsers. If you want a specific format anywhere - then use moment’s formatting method to get it, instead of relying on implicit functionality.

Comment: So its like I want to display timezone only when ambiguous DST is there, in all other cases I don't want to display timezone, so I though of going with toDate()

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because locale data was not being loaded in IE10, which got resolved by importing and adding the locale dynamically into the browser.

The code which resolved my issue is using:

```
const locale = navigator.language
        || 'en-US';
const localeWithoutRegionCode = locale.toLowerCase().split('-')[0];
addLocaleData(require( `intl/locale-data/jsonp/${localeWithoutRegionCode}`));
```